# React losing checked while filtering

Tags: reactjs

I cannot figure out how to add 'active' into the state of users.
For the sake of posting this here I hardcoded some users in the state, but they're supposed to be fetched from an API - and this doesn't come with 'active'. I need to be able to mark the checkboxes so that the specific user becomes active, **also** if active - it has to stay active when doing searches in the list through the text-input, so it doesn't reset. With what I wrote I am getting undefined for `user.active`. Any suggestions?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import UserList from './components/UserList';
import './style/style.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

UserList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function UserList() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      id: 681,
      first_name: 'James',
      last_name: 'Smith',
      email: 'example1',
      gender: 'm',
    },
    {
      id: 3123,
      first_name: 'Richard',
      last_name: 'Greene',
      email: 'example2',
      gender: 'm',
    },
    {
      id: 512,
      first_name: 'Denise',
      last_name: 'Bank',
      email: 'example3',
      gender: 'f',
    },
    {
      id: 654,
      first_name: 'Carl',
      last_name: 'Ross',
      email: 'example4',
      gender: 'm',
    },
  ]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState();
  const [checkedUsers, setCheckedUsers] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await fetch(users);
        result.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() < b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
          if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() > b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
          else return;
        });
        setUsers(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredUsers(
      users.filter(
        (user) =>
          user.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
          user.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [users, search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckedUsers(users.filter((user) => user.active));
  }, [users]);

  const changeChecked = (id) => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        console.log(user);
        if (user.active === '') {
          user.active = true;
        } else user.active = false;
      }
    });
    setUsers(users);
    console.log(checkedUsers);
  };

  return (
    <div className="list-container">
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for users"
          onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      {filteredUsers &&
        filteredUsers.map((user) => (
          <div
            className="user-block"
            key={user.id}
            onClick={() => console.log(user.id, user.active)}>
            <div className="details">
              <h5>
                {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
              </h5>
              <p>{user.email}</p>
            </div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={user.active}
              onClick={(event) => changeChecked(user.id)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here:

1. I think you should map the user after the fetch to add the active with a default value, so it isn't undefined in any case:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       const fetchUsers = async () => {
         try {
           const request = await fetch(users);
           const response = request.map(data => ({...data, active: true})).sort(function (a, b) {
             if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() < b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
             if (a.last_name.toLowerCase() > b.last_name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
             else return;
           });
           setUsers(response);
         } catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
         }
       };
       fetchUsers();
     }, []);
   ```
2. Your filtered users is absolutely useless, you can do that with the user itself and lose the useEffect and the state variables entirely:

   ```
   users.filter(user =>
             user.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
             user.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
         ).map((user) => (
             <div
               className="user-block"
               key={user.id}
               onClick={() => console.log(user.id, user.active)}>
               <div className="details">
                 <h5>
                   {user.first_name} {user.last_name}
                 </h5>
                 <p>{user.email}</p>
               </div>
               <input
                 type="checkbox"
                 checked={user.active}
                 onClick={(event) => changeChecked(user.id)}
               />
             </div>
           )
   ```
3. And last but not least, your changeChecked function is mutating the array. I would use .map as well instead of forEach:

   ```
   const changeChecked = (id) => {
     setUsers(
       users.map(user => {
         if (user.id === id) {
           return {
              ...user,
              active: !user.active
           };
         } else {
            return user;
         }
       })
     );
       console.log(checkedUsers);
   };
   ```